# how to make div  height auto between the header and the footer with overflow auto

Tags: html, css

[jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/c6ABa/51/)

**I got 3 div:**

1 - `<div id="header">` with red color

2 - `<div id="main">` with #FFF2D2color

3 - `<div id="footer">` with red color

I need the `<div id="main">` with auto height and auto overflow.
Thx

```
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <h1>Well came to abc: Club</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="main">

<a href="index.php">&laquo; Back</a><br />
<br />

<h2>Log File</h2>

<p><a href="logfile.php?clear=true">Clear log file</a><p>

<ul class="log-entries">
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:13:18 | Login: aa logged in.
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:19:56 | Login:  logout.
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:22:14 | Login:  logged in.
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:22:16 | Login:  logout
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:26:58 | Login: dgf logged in.
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:26:59 | Login: 35 logout
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:28:03 | Login: aa logged in.
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:28:05 | Login:  logout
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:32:53 | Login: aa logged in.
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:32:55 | Login:  logout
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:35:54 | Login: aa logged in.
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:35:56 | Login: aa logout
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:36:58 | Login: rye logged in.
</li></li><li>2012-06-20 10:13:18 | Login: aa logged in.
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:19:56 | Login:  logout.
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:22:14 | Login:  logged in.
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:22:16 | Login:  logout
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:26:58 | Login: dgf logged in.
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:26:59 | Login: 35 logout
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:28:03 | Login: aa logged in.
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:28:05 | Login:  logout
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:32:53 | Login: aa logged in.
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:32:55 | Login:  logout
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:35:54 | Login: aa logged in.
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:35:56 | Login: aa logout
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:36:58 | Login: rye logged in.
</li>
    <li>2012-06-20 10:37:02 | Login: rye logout
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:39:03 | Login: aa logged in.
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:39:07 | Login: aa logout
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:44:49 | Login: aa logged in.
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:45:00 | Login: aa logout
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:46:10 | Login: aa logged in.
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:46:11 | Login: aa logout
</li><li>2012-06-20 10:53:45 | Login: aa logged in.
</li><li>2012-06-20 11:10:04 | Login: aa logout
</li><li>2012-06-20 11:10:18 | Login: aa logged in.
</li><li>2012-06-20 11:13:16 | Login: aa logged in.
</li><li>2012-06-20 11:48:51 | Login: aa logout
</li><li>2012-06-20 11:49:16 | Login: aa logged in.
</li><li>2012-06-20 11:49:48 | Login: aa logout
</li><li>2012-06-20 11:52:31 | Login: aa logged in.
</li><li>2012-06-20 11:56:13 | Login: aa logout
</li><li>2012-06-20 11:56:26 | Login: aa logged in.
</li><li>2012-06-20 11:56:36 | Login: aa logout
</li><li>2012-06-20 11:57:07 | Login: aa logged in.
</li></ul>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">Copyright 2012, centerwow</div>
  </body>
```

css code:

```
​html { height: 800px; width: 100%;overflow: hidden; }
body { height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; background: #FFFFFF;
  font: 13px/15px Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; }
img { border: none; }

#header { height: 95px; text-align: center; background: red; color: #D4E6F4; }
#header h1 {float:left; padding: 1px;height: 69px; margin: 1px;;width: 100%;clear: both;background: green;}

/* Note: IE 5 & 6 won't understand min-height */

#main { max-height: 100%; 
    height: auto !important; /*Cause footer to stick to bottom in IE 6*/

    margin: 0 auto -100px; /*Allow for footer height*/
    vertical-align:bottom;
    width: 300Px;
    background:#FFF2D2;
    margin:1px;
    overflow:auto;}

#footer { width:100%; height: 2em; padding: 1em; text-align: center; 
  background: red;  color: #D4E6F4;position: absolute;bottom:0; }


​
```

Comment: the `<div id="main">` is not auto height and not auto overflow I want it will be auto height and auto overflow. How can I do that ?Thx

Comment: Can you clarify your requirement?

Comment: I want to see all the content in div id main in the page and if the content is to long it will add scroll.thx

Comment: hi yossi, your requirement is clear to me, well may be I have to use bit of jquery to get it done perfectly in all browsers.
Will it be fine for you to use JQuery?? Or do you need it with only CSS.

Comment: if there is selution with css it is Effective otherwise I use jquery Thx.

Answer (score 2):

You could always "cheat" a bit, and use position absolute on your 3 main divs: http://jsfiddle.net/c6ABa/71/

```
#header { position: absolute; top: 0; height: 95px; }
#main { position: absolute: top: 95px; bottom: 40px; }
#footer { position: absolute; bottom: 0; height: 40px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#main').height($(window).height() - 150);

    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('#main').height($(window).height() - 150);
    });
});
```

It will auto resize `#main` during a window resize.

EDIT:
And here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c6ABa/53/

Comment: I found selution in css position absulate http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/c6ABa/69/ Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Well i have the working version for you, I have used Jquery to achive this, below is the code and fiddle link..

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var mainBlockHeight = windowHeight - $('#footer').height() - $('#header').height() - 28;
    $('#main').height(mainBlockHeight);

});
```

Here is the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/meetsubhajit/c6ABa/73/

EDIT: Here i have fetch the height of footer and header dynamically as later if height of header and footer increases or decreases you won't need to edit the script again.